How to use Bootstrap 4 navtabs with accordions show.bs and hide.bs functionalities?
Is there a way that if I click the Button for Maintab 2 will activate the Maintab 2 Content and will show the accordion content for Collapsible Group Item #2. I'm going to implement it also on the other tabs, but I'm having a problem using the show.bs.tab, show.bs.collapse or other Events related to this.
Check my code below and you can also check the codepen here: https://codepen.io/graydirt/pen/eYawXvg


$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#btn-main2').on('click', function(){
        $('#main2-tab').tab('show'); 
        $('#collapseTwo').collapse('show'); 

        // Scroll to the accordion header
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#collapseTwo').prev('.card-header').offset().top
          }, 500);
        }, 500);
      });
    });
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul style="list-style: none" class="py-5 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <li class="px-2">
      <a id="btn-main2" class="btn btn-primary text-white" role="button">Button for Maintab 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="main1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#main1" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Maintab 1 Content</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="main2-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#main2" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Maintab 2 Content</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="main3-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#main3" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Maintab 3 Content</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="main1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">main1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="main2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
      <div id="accordion">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true">
                Collapsible Group Item #1
              </button>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false">
                Collapsible Group Item #2
              </button>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS. Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false">
                Collapsible Group Item #3
              </button>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="main3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">main3</div>
  </div>




use jQuery for the click event of your button, then activate the second tab.
set the id="btn-main2" to the button


 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#btn-main2').on('click', function(){
        $('#main2-tab').tab('show'); 
        $('#collapseTwo').collapse('show'); 

        // Scroll to the accordion header
        setTimeout(function() {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#collapseTwo').prev('.card-header').offset().top
          }, 500);
        }, 500);
      });
    });
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul style="list-style: none" class="py-5 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <li class="px-2">
      <a id="btn-main2" class="btn btn-primary text-white" role="button">Button for Maintab 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="main1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#main1" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Maintab 1 Content</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="main2-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#main2" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Maintab 2 Content</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="main3-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#main3" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Maintab 3 Content</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="main1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">main1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="main2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
      <div id="accordion">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true">
                Collapsible Group Item #1
              </button>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false">
                Collapsible Group Item #2
              </button>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false">
                Collapsible Group Item #3
              </button>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="main3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">main3</div>
  </div>




I updated my code above, how about that if i click the button it will anchor to the Collapsible Group Item #2?

remove  $('#collapseTwo').collapse('show');

It ain't working, what I mean is it will anchor down smoothly to the Collapsible Group Item #2 title header.

I have updated the code, use full version jQuery and add a scroll down function

thanks! If you can help me here, its the same code but different approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78718933/bootstrap-4-how-to-open-a-navtab-with-accordion-to-another-page-s-if-you-click

your index page should send a param to the tab page. get the param with const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString); and then run the function like the click event
